# How much time does it take for twitter app review?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I would like to know, how much time does it takes for twitter app review? I have searched twitter policies and everywhere but found nowhere. I submitted one week back for twitter app review. Please lemme know how much time does it takes for twitter app review. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to promote on Twitter, your profile and content will be subjected to an approval process. When I started running Twitter Ads, the account approval process only took 24 hours.

Comment: Can you please lemme format to write usecases in twitter.